# CSS Styling for iOS Specific Device - not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile

Hi I am having a major issue with the load of my website on iPhone devices, both safari and google chrome browsers. I am trying to hide the element causing the issue but my Javascript or CSS code does not seem to be doing anything.

This is my Javascript code to detect the iPhone

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
    $('html').addClass('iphone');
}
</script>
```

and my CSS Class is just .iphone .banner-one {display: none;}

Could anyone help me with what I am doing wrong or a better way to fix it? I do NOT want size specific CSS codes as I would like the element to still show up on android/windows devices.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try:

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("banner-one")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("banner-one")[0].remove();
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
        document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(2) > section:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(9)").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
        document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(2) > section:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(9)").remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Still doesn't work though

Comment: @YankinDeez So what you are trying to do is hide the element with the classname of "banner-one" if the user is on iphone right? If this element is causing issues then maybe it would be better to remove it don't you think? Can you give me the HTML file with this element so I can help u out?

Comment: yes, removing it entirely is an option but it's an important design element so I wouldn't want to unless it's the only option left. How would I be able to send you the files?

Comment: the banner-one code is just this

 <img src="images/banner-1-1.png" class="banner-one" alt="Banner"/>

Comment: @YankinDeez I'd need the full html code at least from the root of this element to be able to settle a path to get this element, you can try to post it there https://textuploader.com/ and then send here the url

Comment: Also when i was talking about removing it was not from your code but only on mobile devices by calling .remove()

Comment: Here is the code, the class is actually banner-one__moc

https://textuploader.com/1c0bb

Comment: @YankinDeez okay so I've added three more option you can try, let me know if any worked or none did and will move forward

Comment: thank you! I tried them and still no luck. I'm thinking maybe the device sniffing part isn't working properly?

Comment: @YankinDeez what's a device sniffing part? (im from france)

Comment: This part:     if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {

Comment: What Im saying is I think the CSS is correct but the script isnt triggering it. Because I tested the CSS and did display:none manually and that removed the element

Comment: do you have any ideas why it isnt working or anything else I can try?

Comment: Yes, try to add an id to that element and then try getting it by calling document.getElementById("yourId")